# Write to uninitialized variable: undefined behaviour?

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior

On page 18 of Bjarne Stroustrup's "A Tour of C++" (second edition), he states "for almost all types, the effect of reading from or writing to an uninitialized variable is undefined".

I understand why *reading from* an uninitialized variable is undefined behaviour, but why is *writing to* an uninitialized variable undefined behaviour? Surely I am missing something, because otherwise doing something like `int x;` is completely useless because you cannot read from or write to `x` (i.e. cannot do anything with `x`) without triggering undefined behaviour (assuming `int` is one of the "almost all types" that this applies to).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202447/discussion-on-question-by-robertr-write-to-uninitialized-variable-undefined-beh).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Writing to an uninitialized variable is fine.  The only time you get undefined behavior with uninitialized variables is when you try and read from them before anything is written to them.  Then you have undefined behavior because that value it has is undefined.

Now what is undefined behavior is writing to an object whose lifetime has not begun.  For example if you have a struct like

```
struct foo
{
    std::string str;
};
```

and you acquire memory for it with `malloc` like

```
foo* f = malloc(sizeof(foo));
```

then you can't do

```
f->str = "some text";
```

The reason for this is because `malloc` does't actually give you an object.  All it does is allocate storage for the object, which is not enough to consider that you actually have an object since `std::string` has a non trivial constructor meaning `foo`'s constructor is non trivial as well.  In order for the lifetime of `*f` to start you need to call `foo`'s constructor.  To do that you use [placement new](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new#Placement_new) which will construct the object in the memory you provide to it.  That would look like

```
foo* f = malloc(sizeof(foo));
new(f) foo;
```

This is most likely what Bjarne is trying to talk about.